# deleting database cache after some time codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, caching

I was wondering if there is any workaround to delete `database cache` in codeigniter, say after every 5 hours. by default `database query cache` is persistent and we have to delete it manually.

Can we make `db cache` work like `page level cache` in CI, where we can specify time for cache!

Answer (score 3):

You could make a cron script to call $this->db->cache_delete_all(); and run it every 5h.

Comment: that seems to solve my issue. but isn't there anything in CI so that i do not need to run cron job.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really like the cron job solution since one might forget executing it when installing new server or after maintenance.

I decided to use a little helper to support deletion or old cache file:

**/application/helpers/cache_expire_helper.php:**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

define("CACHE_DIR", APPPATH.'cache/');

if ( ! function_exists('is_cache_valid')) {
    function is_cache_valid($cache_name,$lifespan) {

        if (file_exists(CACHE_DIR.$cache_name)) {
            $last_date = file_get_contents(CACHE_DIR.$cache_name);
            if (abs($last_date - time()) < $lifespan) {
                return true;
            } else {
                file_put_contents(CACHE_DIR.$cache_name,time());
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            file_put_contents(CACHE_DIR.$cache_name,time());
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

**Then, to use it, from the Model:**

```
$this->load->helper('cache_expire');        
if (!is_cache_valid('servers',60 /* seconds */)){
    $this->db->cache_delete('controller', 'comments');
}
.....
```